# PS CC Filter Selections used in Actions

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions, accessibility

The new layer filters is nice but doesn't record when making actions. Before I was able to add 'Select similar layer' in an action and edit all similar layers (because they have different layer names) now it won't recognize the filter as part of a recordable action. Currently I have to use STOPS in actions to get same results with less automation. :(

EXAMPLE:
Automating a batch of multi-layered files with numerous TYPE (text/character) layers. Need to remove all TYPE layers from files without stopping mid batch for each file.

help? Or help write a script? (i don't know scripting)
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have only two options.

1. Revert to a much lower version of PS where the filters are still individually accessible in the manner you wish.
2. Learn massive amounts of JavaScript and "program" around the problems of the newer way of doing things with Filters.

Answer (score 0):

This function and call might help you remove all layers of type 'TEXT'; (I've not tested it so be careful).

```
removeLayers( ArtLayer.TEXT, app.activeDocument );

/**
 * @param {LayerKind} layerKind  The kind/type of layer to filter
 * @param {Document}  psDocument The Photoshop document
 */
function removeLayers( layerKind, psDocument ) {
    for ( var layer in psDocument.artLayers ) {
        if ( layer.kind === layerKind ) {
            layer.remove();
        }
    }
}
```